# How to import Cisco AnyConnect configuration into openconnect?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, openvpn, cisco-anyconnect

I have to use two Cisco AnyConnect VPNs together, which is not possible, so I want to try to import one of their settings into OpenConnect? I am on Windows 10, I don't have VPN connection settings, just EXE setup of AnyConnect. How can I extract its settings to migrate to OpenConnect?